# Is there a list of all Ethereum unit converters?

Tags: tokens, decimals, wei

I'm interested in converting Ether units to wei, plus other custom token amounts where the decimals may be different to 18.

Is there a list of all Ethereum unit converters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an exhaustive list but these are the tools that I know about:

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [ABDK Toolkit](https://toolkit.abdk.consulting/math#convert-number) | Multiple number format conversion (including ETH) |
| [dEth tools](https://tools.deth.net/eth-unit-conversion) | ETH and tokens conversion |
| [Etherchain](https://eth-converter.com/) | ETH conversion |
| [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/unitconverter) | ETH conversion |
| [Eth Utils](https://eth-utils.com/unit) | ETH conversion |
| [Murkin](https://converter.murkin.me/) | ETH conversion |